# What constitutes a 'unique document request'?

Tags: docusignapi

The rules of certification state:

`You may not exceed 1 unique document request per unique envelope per 15 minutes.`

The [Certification Requirements](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/API_Certification_InfoSheet_05_11_16.pdf) details which specific requests are considered a status request, but say nothing more about unique document requests.

Would this API limitation allow me to make multiple GET requests on `/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents` within 15 minutes?

What about multiple GET requests on `/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}/pages/{pageNumber}/page_image` within 15 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

First: As you quote, the no-more-than-once-every-15-minutes-rule is per *specific* envelope, not per integration_id. So if you're looking up the documents associated with different envelopes, you're fine.

If you're listing the documents for a specific envelope frequently, why are you doing that? If you're essentially polling to see if someone has added an attachment to an envelope, that won't fly.

For any call that you're making repeatedly, the real question is why are you doing it?

Unless you have a (very) good explanation of why your repeated calls shouldn't be considered polling, your integration won't pass the review/certification step.

These days, it has become easier and easier to have a listener that can accept [incoming webhook notifications](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/status_and_events.html) from DocuSign.

Use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) (or similar) or start a listener on Heroku and then your app can poll it.

Comment: I've been using the webhook, but it's been less than ideal for tracking signer/document changes and deletion. The GET requests provide much better information (e.g. recipient ID, role names, document page counts) to compare the envelope to my MySQL records, where I find the Connect module lacking. Is there any way around this, or do I need to re-think my data flow?

Comment: Do the connect messages let you know when an event that you're interesting in has occurred? It is fine to do a GET in response to a Connect notification to obtain additional info on the change. If things are happening where there is no Notification, please amend your question to say what those are, specifically. We can then request that the Connect team add them as future events.

Comment: I've followed your advice and taken a second look at the calls I'm making.  A lot of them do seem to be unnecessary, so I'm currently in the middle of some re-writes. I can't test whether these actions trigger the webhook or not right now, but it'd be nice if deleting documents, modifying a recipient's name or email, and deleting recipients could activate the Connect module.